# Андроид студио, кнопка назад

Tags: android, android-studio

В любом месте жмешь кнопку назад на смартфоне, вместо перейти на предыдущую страницу закрывается приложение. Можете подсказать код, что бы при нажатии назад, открывал предыдущую страницу, а не закрывал приложение? В этом пакете
активити.    package com.inc.google;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi; import android.os.Build; import
android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import
android.webkit.WebResourceRequest; import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://google.ru/?");

        WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }


            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N) @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                

 1. Элемент списка

view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        };
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить этот код:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]